# Why isn't this li transforming on replaceWith?

Tags: jquery, replacewith

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<form><input[type="text"]>cool stuff</input></form>');
});
```

When i use this code, the text in the middle shows up, but not the text box I'm looking for. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It's because the HTML you're replacing the `li` with is invalid:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<form><input type="text">cool stuff</form>');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/raee9b2h/)

Also note that replacing an `li` with a `form` is invalid as only `li` elements can be direct children of a `ol` or `ul`. Instead you could `empty()` the current `li`, then `append()` the new `form` to it, or just use `html()` to do this:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).html('<form><input type="text">cool stuff</form>');
});
```

Comment: well that works, but now i cannot type into the field. Any reason why?

Comment: I'm not sure, the fiddle allows me to type fine. Do you have any other event handlers hooked to the `input`, `form` or `ul`?

Comment: Is there an advantage of `empty().append(...)` over using `html(...)`?

Comment: @RickHitchcock not specifically, I just wanted to make it clear to the OP what's happening, although you're right that using `html()` is better practice. I amended the answerr.